# OpenCV 3.0 visual debug with CVV, crash cvv::showImage

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I tried use visual debug like in this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dcf/tutorial_cvv_introduction.html)

```
#define CVVISUAL_DEBUGMODE
#include <opencv2/cvv/debug_mode.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cvv/show_image.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cvv/final_show.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat mat = imread("...");
    imshow("img", mat); // works fine
    waitKey();

    cvv::showImage(mat); // crash on this line

    cvv::finalShow();

    return 0;
}
```

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: Does mat have a size?  If the image isn't loaded correctly this could be a cause of failure.  If you use `cout << mat.size() << endl;` you can check the size of the matrix after loading the image.

Comment: `cv::imshow("Img", mat); cv::waitKey();` works fine with this `cv::Mat`. Mat have normal size.

Comment: Did you ever get cvv to work?

Comment: @Rich no, didn't